# Why upgrading django version to 3.2 makes the project run "ValueError: Empty module name"?

Tags: django, pip, django-3.1, django-3.2

when I upgrade django version from 3.1 to 3.2 and run my django project, I faced this error:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/.../Kamva-Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/.../Kamva-Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/.../Kamva-Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/.../Kamva-Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 398, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/.../Kamva-Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/.../Kamva-Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/.../Kamva-Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/.../Kamva-Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 210, in create
    app_module = import_module(app_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1011, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _sanity_check
ValueError: Empty module name
```

It just worked well, but after the upgrading, it doesn't run properly.

Comment: Try something from https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdjango%5D+ValueError%3A+Empty+module+name

Comment: @phd I have checked them. I think it is related to django version (with django==3,1 it works)